# Select a word in a drop down menu in Excel, but have it equal a number value in the formula bar

Tags: excel

I would like to be able to select a Fixture Type from a drop down menu, but selecting that cell, the formula bar will show the respective wattage. (e.g. Selecting Fixture Type 'A' will have that cell to actually equal "30", but I would still like to see that I've selected Fixture 'A'.)

I gave an example in the image I've attached.

```
A * 3 = 90    
XR * 4 = 4
M * 5 = 352
A2 * 6 = 270
C * 1 = 21.5
-------------
Total = 737.5
```

Excel Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the exact nature of the drop down menu but you could always put this formula to the C column and get the results the way you wanted:

```
=INDEX($T$3:$T$36;MATCH(A3;$S$3:$S$36;0))*B3
```

Or in VBA you can use the Find method and offset(0,1)

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you select from a list in Excel, you get your selected option, not it's respective value in another column of your table. To do what you described, I suggest the following:
Add **Watts** as a new column (in column C). Then use `vlookup` function to lookup the watt. For example, the formula in `C3` should be:

```
=vlookup(A3,$S$3:$T$36,2,FALSE)
```

Now when you choose a fixture, column C will have the watts and you can use `sumproduct` to calculate the total.

Note: if you want your form to look better, use `iferror`:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A3,$S$3:$T$36,2,FALSE),0)
```

This makes sure that if the cell is empty, then instead of `N\A` you see zero.